# Two chain graph with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains, tikz-graphdrawing

This is what I'm trying to draw:
[image]

I was able to draw this graph (code below):
[image]
But I am not able to create another change above the first one, nor "labeling" the nodes with other nodes.

Any ideas?

What I have done so far:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
node distance = 3mm and 9mm,
start chain = A going right,
 dot/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=1mm,
               node contents={}, join, on chain=A},           
rdot/.style = {dot, fill=red, minimum size=1.5mm},
bdot/.style = {dot, fill=blue, minimum size=1.5mm},
gdot/.style = {dot, fill=green, minimum size=1.5mm},
ydot/.style = {dot, fill=yellow, minimum size=1.5mm},
                    ]
\node[dot,label=below:0];             % A-1
\node[rdot,label=below:$\frac{1}{10}$];
\node[dot,coordinate];
\node[rdot,label=below:$\frac{3}{10}$];
\node[dot,coordinate];           % A-5
\node[ydot,label=below:$\frac{5}{10}$];
\node[dot,coordinate];  
\node[rdot,label=below:$\frac{7}{10}$];
\node[dot,coordinate];
\node[rdot,label=below:$\frac{9}{10}$];
\node[dot,label=below:1];  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative version without the use of libraries, but with a `\foreach` statement and some `\if` statements.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=1mm},           
    rdot/.style = {dot, fill=red, minimum size=1.5mm},
    bdot/.style = {dot, fill=blue, minimum size=1.5mm},
    gdot/.style = {dot, fill=green!70!black, minimum size=1.5mm},
    ydot/.style = {dot, fill=yellow, minimum size=1.5mm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x/\style in {0,1/gdot,3/bdot,5,7/gdot,9/ydot,10}{%
    \ifodd\x
    \ifnum\x=5
        \node[ydot, label=below:$\frac{\x}{10}$] at (\x,0) {};
    \else
        \node[rdot, label=below:$\frac{\x}{10}$, label={[\style, label distance=1pt]}] at (\x,0) {};
    \fi
    \else
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nums{\x/10}
        \node[dot, label=below:\nums] at (\x,0) {};
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Alternative code without foreach

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=1mm},           
    rdot/.style = {dot, fill=red, minimum size=1.5mm},
    bdot/.style = {dot, fill=blue, minimum size=1.5mm},
    gdot/.style = {dot, fill=green!70!black, minimum size=1.5mm},
    ydot/.style = {dot, fill=yellow, minimum size=1.5mm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);

\node[dot, label=below:0] at (0,0) {};

\node[rdot, label=below:$\frac{1}{10}$, label={[gdot, label distance=1pt]}] at (1,0) {};
\node[rdot, label=below:$\frac{3}{10}$, label={[bdot, label distance=1pt]}] at (3,0) {};
\node[ydot, label=below:$\frac{5}{10}$] at (5,0) {};
\node[rdot, label=below:$\frac{7}{10}$, label={[gdot, label distance=1pt]}] at (7,0) {};
\node[rdot, label=below:$\frac{9}{10}$, label={[ydot, label distance=1pt]}] at (9,0) {};

\node[dot, label=below:1] at (10,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want a solution with `chains`, just let me know. I'll provide one.

Comment: your solution is great. I will appreciate if you make each node manually, since the use of `foreach` make things harder to understand, and also I'm interested in extending it to other drawings as well. Use less nodes if it is too grueling. Thanks!

Comment: @omerbp If you don't understand something from the code above, you can ask here in the comments. I'll be happy to explain. If you don't have experience with `\foreach` statements, it might seem odd, but they are very straightforward. I mean, especially if you need to do this multiple times, doing each node is going to be tedious and also make your code long. I'll include a normal version though.

Comment: @omerbp Did you want the other version using `chain` or not? It wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Your alternative solution is great, Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Additional color circles you can add with

```
\begin{scope}[dot/.append style={reset join}]
\node[gdot, above=of A-2];
\node[bdot, above=of A-4];
\node[gdot, above=of A-8];
\node[ydot, above=of A-10];
\end{scope}
```

after main nodes:

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm and 9mm,
start chain = A going right,
 dot/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=1mm,
               node contents={}, join, on chain=A},
rdot/.style = {dot, fill=red, minimum size=1.5mm},
bdot/.style = {dot, fill=blue, minimum size=1.5mm},
gdot/.style = {dot, fill=green, minimum size=1.5mm},
ydot/.style = {dot, fill=yellow, minimum size=1.5mm},
                    ]
\node[dot,label=below:0];             % A-1
\node[rdot,label=below:$\frac{1}{10}$];
\node[dot,coordinate];
\node[rdot,label=below:$\frac{3}{10}$];
\node[dot,coordinate];           % A-5
\node[ydot,label=below:$\frac{5}{10}$];
\node[dot,coordinate];
\node[rdot,label=below:$\frac{7}{10}$];
\node[dot,coordinate];
\node[rdot,label=below:$\frac{9}{10}$];
\node[dot,label=below:1];
%
\begin{scope}[dot/.append style={reset join}]
\node[gdot, above=of A-2];
\node[bdot, above=of A-4];
\node[gdot, above=of A-8];
\node[ydot, above=of A-10];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```